# How to reduce the time of clang_complete search through boost

Tags: vim, boost, clang, code-completion, clang-complete

I like using clang with vim.

The one problem that I always have is that whenever I include boost, clang goes through boost library every time I put "." after a an object name. It takes 5-10 seconds.

Since I don't make changes to boost headers, is there a way to cache the search through boost?
If not, is there a way to remove boost from the auto-completion search?

**update (1)** in response to answer by adaszko
after 
:let g:clang_use_library = 1

1. I type a name of a variable.
2. I press ^N. Vim starts to search through boost tree. it auto-completes the variable.
3. i press "." and get the following errors:

> ```
> Error detected while processing function ClangComplete:
> line   35:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> Press ENTER or type command to continue
> Error detected while processing function ClangComplete:
> line   35:
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> Press ENTER or type command to continue
> Error detected while processing function ClangComplete:
> line   35:
> NameError: name 'vim' is not defined
> Press ENTER or type command to continue
> Error detected while processing function ClangComplete:
> line   40:
> E121: Undefined variable: l:res
> Press ENTER or type command to continue
> Error detected while processing function ClangComplete:
> line   40:
> E15: Invalid expression: l:res
> Press ENTER or type command to continue
> Error detected while processing function ClangComplete:
> line   58:
> E121: Undefined variable: l:res
> Press ENTER or type command to continue
> Error detected while processing function ClangComplete:
> line   58:
> E15: Invalid expression: l:res
> Press ENTER or type command to continue
> ```

... and there is no auto-compeltion

**update (2)** 
not sure if clang_complete should take care of the issue with boost. vim without plugins does search through boost.
superuser has an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/77800/vims-autocomplete-how-to-prevent-vim-to-read-some-include-files) to comment out search through boost dirs with `set include=^\\s*#\\s*include\ \\(<boost/\\)\\@!`

Comment: What's your value of Vim's variable g:clang_use_library?

Comment: @adaszko  `:let g:clang_use_library` returns `g:clang_use_library   #0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/77800/vims-autocomplete-how-to-prevent-vim-to-read-some-include-files), you can add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
:set include=^\\s*#\\s*include\ \\(<boost/\\)\\@!
```

(the question of caching the search through boost is still open though)

Answer (score 4):

So, you have at least two options.  Option #1 is to set `g:clang_use_library`
to `1`.  Here's what `:help g:clang_use_library` says about it:

```
Instead of calling the clang/clang++ tool use libclang directly. This
gives access to many more clang features. Furthermore it automatically
caches all includes in memory. Updates after changes in the same file will
therefore be a lot faster.
```

This requires working setup of Python Vim integration though.

Option #2 is to set `g:clang_complete_auto` to `0` by which you disable
automatic completion after `->`, `.`, `::` and may use `<C-x> <C-o>` instead
to manually invoke clang_complete whenever you wish.

I use both.

Comment: Perhaps this will improve in future versions.

Comment: Looks to me like a material for a separate question on StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've done a lot of performance enhancements to clang_complete, you can check about this at issue [#187](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/pull/187). Big part of the problem was just weak script performance due to non optimized code.